# unable to find the socket transport "username" (cURL or composer inside docker container)

Tags: php, ssl, docker, curl, proxy

I'm behind a corporate proxy that requires user/pw authentication. I entered the credentials in my docker client on a Windows 10 machine. These settings used to work in the past. I use the same credentials as `--build-arg` in my `docker build` processes and it also works. I can build my openSUSE-based image and run it.

The image contains cURL and composer (for PHP development). I can use these tools outside of my corporate proxy network without problems. However, inside the company, I try:

`curl --silent --show-error https://getcomposer.org/installer | php` or

`composer self-update`

and I get this error message:

*failed to open stream: Unable to find the socket transport "xxx" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?*

where xxx is my username from the docker proxy settings *username:password@123.456.789.0:port*

As far as I understand, curl and composer think that my username is a protocol that should be used to download files. This should probably rather be "http" or "ssl" etc. !?

Any help is greatly appreciated! I'm installing curl by using zypper: `zypper --non-interactive install curl php7 php7-curl php7-openssl php-composer...`

Comment: I dug through the source code of the composer installer, apparently it uses parse_url to parse the proxy URL. Calling parse_url('username:password@123.456.789.0:1000') classifies "username" as a scheme. Try adding http:// or https:// to the proxy URL in the docker settings.

Comment: Thank you very much! I added http:// and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

Proxies are hell for development tools. You have to take into account the proxy config for each tool. 
My advice is to install a tool to transparently route all the traffic from the host to the proxy.

Once such tool for windows is [proxycap](http://www.proxycap.com). Once you install it on your machine, all traffic should be redirected to the proxy, and you don't have to configure proxy settings for any tool.

Comment: That is problably a good idea, indeed. However, Hassan's approach (s. above) worked for me, so there is no need for routing all the traffic.